# ViewdidLoad & unloading

Tags: ios, memory-management

I am having trouble with using up a lot of memory at the moment and i am doing everything i can to shave off and optimize my code where memory is concerned... Currently my game has most of it's Nib files load all of its variables in ViewDidLoad, Now my question is that in my viewDidUnload that i should not only nil everything in viewdidunload but i should also release it? Even if it is not an IBoutlet?

Also if i release and nil it IBoutlet or NSMutablearray..whatever should i also release it in dealloc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Release your instance variables on dealloc and set your properties variables to nil on viewDidUnload.

Also, why dont you enable ARC (Automatic Reference Counting) for your project on Xcode. 
If you are new to memory management on Objective-C I'll highly recommend you to take advantage of this functionality. Is better than a garbage collector, it automatically detects when an object is not longer needed and release it.

Comment: I am not a complete noob with memory management i am just unsure on some points...And the project has become quite large and i fear switching to ARC will cause more problems than it solves

Comment: Thanks by the way, Also should i also release and nil non property variables that have been allocated in ViewDidUnload?

Comment: You shouldn't allocate anything on ViewDidUnload, this method is called when there is low memory. Take a look into this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/5981580/454165. It explains the functionality of viewDidUnload and dealloc, they aren't called at the same time.